# Git commit not finished but can't continue on that machine

Tags: git

Sometimes I run into the problem of having uncommitted code on a workstation that is not ready for a commit but needs to be completed on a different workstation or laptop.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem, such as a "soft commit" or some other way of transferring the changes to another machine to work on them elsewhere?

I would prefer not to be forced to commit and push changes that are not properly implemented.

Comment: this post is rather hard to read (wall of text). Would you mind [edit]ing it into a better shape?

Comment: ..sounds like you're after `git stash`... ?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead yes but can I move a git stash over to another machine easily?

Comment: ***All*** Git commits are "soft commits".

Comment: Not really a duplicate, because it approaches the problem the other way around, but related: [Should I use git stash to save ongoing changes of my project and push it to github to access in other computers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/324649/should-i-use-git-stash-to-save-ongoing-changes-of-my-project-and-push-it-to-gith)

Answer (score 13):

The following assumes your local repo is a clone of a repo on another server, e.g. github; and that you have rights to make changes to the upstream server. In my example, I've called this upstream repo "origin". Run `git remote show` to list other repos, this may give you a hint as to what it's called.

I would suggest making a branch, then you can check out the branch on another machine. In fact, if you make a branch as soon as you start work, you can "commit" to your branch, have a trail and backup of your work, without having to have a stable codeset. Once you are happy with your work, you can merge it back into your "master" branch.

- To branch your repo: `git checkout -b MyNewBranch`
- To push committed changes of your new branch: `git push origin MyNewBranch`
- To check out a branch on another machine: `git checkout MyNewBranch`
- To switch to another branch (e.g. "master"): `git checkout master`
- When in master, to merge MyNewBranch back in: `git merge MyNewBranch`
- To list branches: `git branch`

Comment: Yes, always working in your own private branch essentially solves this problem.  You can commit as often as you want without affecting anyone else.  Even better is to create a new branch every time you start work on a new feature or start fixing a new defect.  This makes it very easy to jump back and forth between codebases.

Comment: Also, and the reason I do this: if you make a mistake halfway through, you can go to previous commits on the current branch. Or, jump back, grab a piece of it, jump forward and apply.

Comment: Wouldn't this method also include the incomplete commits in the merged master branch?

Comment: Yes, and (in my opinion) that's probably not a bad thing. If you don't want that, do the above, then instead of committing your code, create a diff (which includes all file changes, but no commits), apply it to a fresh copy of the branch, then push that.

Comment: regarding "*To switch to another branch do `git branch -d master`*", I'm confused, doesn't that ask git to *delete* the master branch??  (that's the impression I get from reading the git branch manual anyway)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I know it's a little late .. but the answer's been edited now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I *commit* it. The I *push* it to **personal branch**, check out on the other side and amend. And delete the personal branch when done.

Of course you can push directly between the repos, you can use bundle or `format-patch`/`am`, but a personal branch is by far the easiest solution. And rewriting history is not a big deal as long as it's not pushed to any shared branch. In many projects people are *supposed* to rewind the feature branches to keep them easier to understand for review.

Comment: i agree with this approach

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git diff` to create a patch and then apply it on other machine. Or you can create a temporary commit, then pull it from other machine. You can even create a temporary branch on some other machine, push your temporary commit there, then delete the branch.

My favorite method is the second one: creating a temporary commit, then going to another machine and doing something like this:

```
$ git fetch ssh://first_machine/path/to/repo whatever_branch_i_was_working_on
$ git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
$ git reset HEAD^
```

Comment: Why so complicated and not just using [`git format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch)?

Comment: Not really different from `git diff`. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: `git format-patch deadbee..badcab1e` - It creates `.patch` files for every commit separately with nice name and commit message preserved.

Comment: Does it also create a patch for changes that are not yet committed? Does it separate current index and things that are not yet staged? Looks like it doesn't.

Comment: No, not for the uncommitted/unstaged changes. But since a commit does not hurt anybody else as long as you don't push it should be OK to commit (with a clear message that says "WIP" - work in progress).

Answer (score 0):

The easy approach is the one you describe: copy the `.git` hidden directory and project files to another machine where you can either commit and finish up, or just continue working.

The `.git` directory is where your git history is kept, so preserving this along with the actual files keeps your entire project history intact.

If you are permanently done using the original machine, I'd probably recommend this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have answered, with Git you shouldn't care about non-finished code in your personal branches. However, if for some reason, you really really really don't want your unfinished work to ever touch the main repo, you can utilize Git's distributed nature!

There is a simple tool named `git bundle` that can help you easily pass changes around without a central repository. First, clone the repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife.git working_copy_1
cd working_copy_1
```

make some changes and commit them to a temporary branch:

```
git checkout -b tmp_branch
git commit -a -m "temporary changes"
```

Now, bundle them changes:

```
git bundle create ../tmp.bundle tmp_branch
```

Now you have a bundle file you can mail to your new machine. How do you use it there? Let's create a new working copy:

```
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife.git working_copy_2
cd working_copy_2
```

we need to treat our bundle as another remote, so we can fetch the changes from it

```
git remote add tmp ../tmp.bundle
git fetch tmp
```

since the whole point was to transfer the changes without leaving a trace, we'll want to squash them into the working copy in order to lose the temp commit:

```
git merge tmp/tmp_branch --squash
```

and all that is left is to remove the temporary remote:

```
git remote remove tmp
```

VIOLA! The changes were transferred to the new working copy without leaving a trace of neither branch nor commit!

But really - this process is quite long and cumbersome. This is Git, not SVN - there really shouldn't be any reason not to push your personal branch to the central repo.